# Can core php mysql function be used in Yii Framework?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

Can we use core PHP functions in Yii framework?

Here, I have a core php function

```
function abc_function(){
$query=mysql_query("select emp_id, days from tmp_emp_work where comp_id='$comp_id' AND active=1");
$count=mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($count) {
    $del_existing=mysql_query("DELETE from temp_t_balances where com_id='$comp_id'");
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($query);
    while ($row) {
        $emp_id=$row['emp_id'];
        $array=dis_t_bal ($emp_id,$com_id);
        $start_bal=$array[0];
        $taken=$array[1];
        $comp_days=$array[2];
        $remain_bal=$array[3];
        $booked=$array[4];
        $true_bal=$array[5];
        $all_days=$array[6];
        $insert_bal=mysql_query("INSERT into temp_t_bal values ('','$comp_id','$emp_id','$start_bal','$taken','$remain_bal','$booked','$true_bal')");
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($query);
    }
}
}
```

Is this possible? Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes it is possible. But it is definitely not advisable. Why not make use of the framework's classes? Kinda defeats the purpose of using frameworks in this case

Comment: You should not use `mysql_` functions anywhere. They are deprecated (use PDO or mysqli instead, and prepared statements). Best way would be to use Yii's built-in method in your case.

Comment: Yii have good choice of using QueryBuilder http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder instead of ActiveRecord. QueryBuilder is more easier specially to write query and getting records in array.

Comment: why to jump in pool if you want to get wet ?

Comment: What are suggestions for me? Since I have lots of functions written using mysql_ functions. Please suggest. Do we have any extensions or method to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You have read all the comments about why you shouldn't do it. That's for you to evaluate.

However, the ability to submit queries directly are supported.

As an example

```
$sqlQuery = "SELECT employee_id, holidays
               FROM employee_work
              WHERE company_id='$company_id' AND emp_active=1';

$listEmployee = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sqlQuery)->queryAll();


foreach ($listEmployee as $itemEmployee){
   print_r($itemEmployee);
}
```

Note that the above query is not safe, and can be subject to SQL injection. Yii offers a solution to upgrade the query to a safer format by using binding.

```
$listEmployee = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT employee_id, holidays
                                                 FROM employee_work
                                                WHERE company_id=:company_id
                                                  AND emp_active=1')
                              ->bindValue(':company_id',$company_id)
                              ->queryAll();
```

You also have access to the query() method for queries that do not return a resultset

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand('DELETE * FROM customer')->query();
```

References : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao

Comment: It'd be much better with these examples to just post the safe version.

Comment: Agreed, but I posted the unsafe because the OP was looking to convert existing queries. Point taken.

Comment: Some people, especially when in a hurry, have a habit of taking the first thing that works. If it's your dangerously vulnerable example, then that's what goes into their code.

Comment: I don't mean to degrade this post into a discussion, but I was not in a hurry to paste a solution. I took the time to provide a solution that will satisfy the initial request of the OP, which is to port existing queries as is, and then explained how this could/should be improved, and why. Surely someone can read past my comment "...the above query is not safe, and can be subject to SQL injection....". I have explained my point and so have you. Let's leave it at that.